# XF 2.0 Admin panel path change

Tags: xenforo

2.0 Library is Empty How to change Admin Panel Path?

Or

hello is there a way to rename the route from admin.php to something else? if so is there a video i can watch or do so i can rename it please?

Comment: Even if you modify admin.php you still need to modify a few other templates and php files.  I would recommend just protecting your admin.php with .htaccess and forcing moderators/admins to use 2FA

Answer (score 0):

Renaming admin.php or moving it's location is a bad idea and would require you changing other templates and php files as well.  This is not how the system is intended to be used.

Instead of changing the path, just password protect admin.php with regular authentication and force your moderators and admins to use 2 factor authentication.

This will solve any security issues that you were trying to solve by renaming it.